# Retrieve list and nested list

Tags: flutter

I want to retrieve a list and a nested list  which is checklists[] and checklistResultItems[], how can I do that?

```
{

    "target": null,
    "checklists": [ //this list
        {
            "roomID": 1078,
            "completedTasks": 2,
            "checklistResultItems": [ //and this list
                {
                    "photo": null
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my TaskDetailsModel

```
 List<dynamic>? checklists;
TaskDetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        checklists = jsonDecode(json['checklists'])
            .map((dynamic item) => CheckListModel.fromJson(item))
            .toList();
      }
```

This is my CheckListModel

```
  List<CheckListResultItemsModel>? checklistResultItems;
CheckListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        checklistResultItems = json['checklistResultItems'];
        if (json['checklistResultItems'] != null) {
          checklistResultItems = <CheckListResultItemsModel>[];
          json['checklistResultItems'].forEach((v) {
            checklistResultItems?.add(CheckListResultItemsModel.fromJson(v));
          });
        }
      }
```

This is my CheckListResultItems model

```
  CheckListResultItemsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    checklistResultItemID = json['checklistResultItemID'];
    checklistItemID = json['checklistItemID'];
    checklistItemName = json['checklistItemName'];
    checklistItemInfo = json['checklistItemInfo'];
    checkListResultID = json['checkListResultID'];
    checked = json['checked'];
    unableToComplete = json['unableToComplete'];
    comments = json['comments'];
    photo = json['photo'];
  }
```

How I retrieve my data from API, I am currently getting this error `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`.

```
 getTaskDetailsApi(int businessID) async {
    try {
      String url = ApiEndpoint.getTaskDetailsByBusinessID
          .replaceAll("{id}", businessID.toString());
      CommonResponse response = await apiClient.get(url);

      if (response.success! && response.fullResponse != null) {
        final responseData = response.fullResponse.data;
        List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(responseData);
        List<TaskDetailsModel> taskDetails = body
            .map((dynamic item) => TaskDetailsModel.fromJson(item))
            .toList();    
        return taskDetails;
      } else {
        Utils.showErrorSnackBar(response.message);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Utils.showErrorSnackBar(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TaskDetailsModel`, you are doing `jsonDecode` again for the `json/map` object.

Try replace first code block with..

```
List<CheckListModel>? checklists;
TaskDetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        checklists = (json['checklists'] as List)
            .map((dynamic item) => CheckListModel.fromJson(item))
            .toList();
      }
```

**Edited**

And the second block(`CheckListModel`) should be like..

```
List<CheckListResultItemsModel>? checklistResultItems;
CheckListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        //checklistResultItems = json['checklistResultItems'];//remove this line
        if (json['checklistResultItems'] != null) {
          checklistResultItems = <CheckListResultItemsModel>[];
          json['checklistResultItems'].forEach((v) {
            checklistResultItems?.add(CheckListResultItemsModel.fromJson(v));
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: still getting the same error...

Comment: You are getting `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type  'List<CheckListResultItemsModel>?'`, right?

Comment: Both are different, and I updated my answer, please review is and update.

Comment: Somehow still same error...

Comment: And no I am getting `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type  'String'`

Comment: Sorry, I commented different line, updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252077/discussion-between-wuuyungwuu-and-alex-sunder-singh).

Comment: How do i retrieve nested list

Comment: As we discussed in chat.

Answer (score 0):

```
 photo = json['photo'] ?? "";
```

For  "target": null, do the same . your problem will be solved

Comment: still get the same error. i still have other items to retrieve but i didnt show all  because there's too much code